# What is and what are the use for an " AINV preconditioner " or " SAINV "?

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, computational-geometry, computational-mathematics

In an article that I'm reading there is a mention to this "thing" and I absolutely don't know anything about it, for me it could be anything.

I noticed that this thing is somehow related to the math behind 3D computer generated simulations ( cloths ? fluids ? ) and to a specific way of distributing a set of points onto a surface, ( maybe there are relations to the Poisson distribution ? ) .

Apparently this thing is generally useful non only for realtime graphics but for 3D imaging in general, anyone knows what this thing is a what is actually good for ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a source for this article you are talking about.

Comment: @FPE it's not in digital form, there is also just a mention to this name. The domain of the article is about 3D physics simulations and 3D imaging, mostly computer generated stuff for 3D discrete topology/mesh .

Comment: See http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2009/179481/ (you could have tried Googling it yourself, I believe). "AINV" means Approximate Inverse. To solve equations like $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a matrix, a method is to find a matrix $M$ such that $MA$ is almost the identity (i.e. only a few coefficients differ from $0$), and so that computing $Mb$ is *fast*.
This implies that finding solutions to $MAx=Mb$ is easier than solving the previous system, and narrows the search space for solutions to the initial system.

Comment: My guess is : this is probably about some "randomizer" factor, this AINV is probably being used to shuffle things around before and it creates a matrix for you that will generate pseudo-random result ? I still have no idea how this happens and what are the principles behind it assuming that my guess is correct.

Comment: @FPE searching for _AINV preconditioner_ doesn't give me this kind of results back, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: I translated my comment to a CW answer, so that you can accept it and close this question. If you have more detailed questions about AINV, it is better to open a new question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2009/179481/. "AINV" means Approximate Inverse. To solve equations like $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a matrix of size $n$, a method is to find a matrix $M$ such that $MA$ is almost the identity (i.e. only a few coefficients differ from those of $I_n$), and so that computing $Mb$ is *fast*.